# Inspect element from console

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-devtools

Google Chrome has a feature where you can take an element object in the console (maybe represented as a jQuery result set), and jump to the corresponding element in the element inspector.

This is the inverse of the `$0` feature which allows you to refer in the console to an element that is already selected in the element inspector.

I've used that feature in the past but right now I can't find it.  How is it accessed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `inspect(element)`, e.g. `inspect(document.body)` (which you can just enter into the console). See: [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference#inspect)